# Spring Security authenticating RESTful web service

Tags: rest, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on adding basic authentication to my RESTful web service (implemented using Spring MVC) with Spring Security having never really used it before. Right now I'm simply using an in-memory `UserService` with the intention of adding a repository-based one later.

```
<security:http>
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="guest" password="guest"
                authorities="ROLE_GUEST" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

This works fine, i.e. sending the following request grants me access to the desired resource (where the encoded string is admin:admin):

```
GET /user/v1/Tyler HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

And sending the following request gives me an Error 403 (where the encoded string is guest:guest):

```
GET /user/v1/Tyler HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q=
```

However, sending a request where the provided username is *not* contained in the `UserService` does not result in an Error 403 as I expected (or at least desired) but instead continues prompting for a username and password. E.g. (where the encoded string is user:user):

```
GET /user/v1/Tyler HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjp1c2Vy
```

Is there additional configuration required to respond with an Error 403 when unrecognized user credentials are provided? How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly,

`403 Forbidden` should be used when user is already authenticated but is not authorized to perform particular action. In your example `guest` is successfully authenticated but is not granted permission to see page because he is just a guest.

You should use `401 Unauthorized` to indicate that your user was not authenticated successfully.

More on HTTP errors codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_401#4xx_Client_Error

Secondly,

you can specify your custom behavior by extending `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.
There is `protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse AuthenticationException failed)` method that you can override and do whatever is adequate. In default implementation that method is empty.

Spring Security docs on injecting custom filter: [CLICK](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-custom-filter)

Edit:

What Spring Security does each time your authentication input is invalid:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
...
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + realmName + "\"");
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
```

So, the default behavior is correct. User is sent 401 and is asked to provide valid login/credentials.

Before overriding, try to understand the default behavior. Source code: [CLICK](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java)

Comment: Thanks, Maciej. You're right, this is correct behavior after all. Good to know how to inject a custom filter though.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this in a client like wget or curl. You browser nags you several times for Basic redentials if your are rejected with 401. This is probably the case here.

Comment: I'm using an HTTP client for Mac OSX (similar to Fiddler for Windows). I assumed since it was explicitly giving a 403 for one case that it would do the same for the other case.